# Problem with macros and drawing rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, draw

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I have a problem with the use of macros.

Let's say that I have created a macro that draws rectangles.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, landscape]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\rect[4]{
\draw (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4);}

 \begin{tikzpicture}    
\rect{1}{2}{3}{4};   
\end{tikzpicture}       

\end{document}
```

It works. Now I would like to create a macro that join the first vertices of two rectangles. I searched on the Internet and found a way to gets the coordinate of the first vertex of a rectangle.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, landscape]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}     

\begin{document}    

\def\generatex#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \toks0={#2}%
  \edef\next{\def\expandafter\noexpand\csname varx#1\endcsname{\the\toks0 }}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\next}

\def\generatey#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \toks0={#2}%
  \edef\next{\def\expandafter\noexpand\csname vary#1\endcsname{\the\toks0 }}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\next}    

\newcommand\rect[5]{
\draw (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4);
\generatex{#5}{#1};
\generatey{#5}{#2};}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\rect{1}{2}{3}{4}{rectone};
\rect{10}{5}{2}{3}{recttwo};
\draw(\varxrectone,\varyrectone)--(\varxrecttwo,\varyrecttwo);    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This works again. But, let's say that I would like to define a general macro doing this. I tried the following but it doesn't work :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, landscape]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}     

\begin{document}    

\def\generatex#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \toks0={#2}%
  \edef\next{\def\expandafter\noexpand\csname varx#1\endcsname{\the\toks0 }}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\next}

\def\generatey#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \toks0={#2}%
  \edef\next{\def\expandafter\noexpand\csname vary#1\endcsname{\the\toks0 }}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\next}    

\newcommand\rect[5]{
\draw (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4);
\generatex{#5}{#1};
\generatey{#5}{#2};}

\newcommand\join[2]{
\draw(\varx#1,\vary#1)--(\varx#2,\vary#2);}    

 \begin{tikzpicture}

\rect{1}{2}{3}{4}{rectone};
\rect{10}{5}{2}{3}{recttwo};    
\join{rectone}{recttwo};  

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Any idea ? I am new to LaTeX and I am sure that all I wrote is terrible, but don't judge me please ! Thanks !!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you ! Any idea for my problem ?

Comment: All of this is already included in the Ti*k*Z system. If you make those rectangles nodes, then the coordinates of the corners are stored in anchors. Internally this looks a bit like what you are doing here, but is IMHO way simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
\newcommand\join[2]{
  \draw(\varx#1,\vary#1)--(\varx#2,\vary#2);}
```

you need to use `\csname ... \endcsname` to construct a control sequence from its name. For example, `\csname varx#1\endcsname`.

LaTeX2e' internal macro `\@nameuse{<csname>}` is helpful when you need to use the `\csname ... \endcsname` structure frequently. Say, you can write

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\join[2]{
  \draw(\@nameuse{varx#1},\@nameuse{vary#1})--(\@nameuse{varx#2},\@nameuse{vary#2});}
\makeatother
```

---

A further simplified example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, landscape]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[french]{babel}     

\newcommand\rect[5]{
  \draw (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4);
  % store #1 in macro \varx<#5>
  \expandafter\def\csname varx#5\endcsname{#1};
  % store #2 in macro \vary<#5>
  \expandafter\def\csname vary#5\endcsname{#2};}

\newcommand{\useCoords}[1]{\useCoordX{#1}, \useCoordY{#1}}
\newcommand{\useCoordX}[1]{\csname varx#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\useCoordY}[1]{\csname vary#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\join[2]{
  \draw (\useCoords{#1}) -- (\useCoords{#2});}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \rect{1}{2}{3}{4}{rectone};
  \rect{10}{5}{2}{3}{recttwo};
  \join{rectone}{recttwo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If open to use LaTeX2e internals ([doc `macros2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/macros2e) gives nice intro to them), you can use

- `\@namedef{<cmd>} ...` to replace `\expandafter\def\csname <cmd>\endcsname ...` and
- `\@nameuse{<cmd>}` to replace `\csname <cmd>\endcsname`.

Comment: Thank you ! It works very well :)

Answer (score 1):

All these mechanisms are already part of Ti*k*Z. For instance, the rectangle connections are as simple as

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[local bounding box=A] (1,2) rectangle (3,4);
 \draw[local bounding box=B] (10,5) rectangle (2,3);
 \draw (A.south west) -- (B.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a plethora of shapes with anchors. For the purposes you are describing there already exist built-in tools in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Actually, it was rather a way to understand how to store the argument of a macro, than the need to join my two rectangles... But thank you for your help !!

Comment: @Henry I was assuming that. This answer is also to tell you that Ti*k*Z is "one step ahead". You could think it is a good idea to store, for a shape named `A`, the x and y coordinates in some macros `\shapeAx` and `\shapeAy`, which is similar to what you propose. But what if some user has a sharp called `Ax`? That's why pgf has mechanisms which schematically defines a macro `\def\coordsA{\pgf@x=<x>\pgf@y=<y>}` with two dimensions `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`. With that mechanism you can store an arbitrary amount of attributes without running out of name space.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you for your help and your explanations !